# Why window.performance.now() could return the same fraction part?

Tags: javascript, timestamp

I've faced some weird behavior of `window.performance.now()`.
It returns values with the same fraction part all the time.

All the data below is from statistics, can't reproduce it by myself.

Here is possible values (`N` represent the ms number, it's counting normally):

```
N (whole number)
N.995
N.99500000001
N.99500000002
N.995000000003
N.00000000001
N.000000000001
N.000000000004
```

So, every time it's a whole number (or close to it) or has the fraction part close to `.995`.

This goes from different users, all from Windows (XP|Vista|7|10) and most from Chrome browser ( 59.0.3071.115, 55.0.2883.87, 49.0.2623.112 ), few from Firefox ( 52.0 ).

At the same time, it happens not for all Windows users, most of them are returns different fraction parts.

The statistics are collected from multiple websites and only happens for some of them, and everything started just recently (a week ago). The `window.performance.now()` function is not re-defined, it still shows 'native code' (via `.toString()`).

Any ideas why it could happens?

Comment: Why do you think this is a bug? Do you use it to benchmark completely different operations? Probably that's really just the time it takes?

Comment: @idmean because before last week it was behave normally. And it still behave normaly for most of cases. Something changed, but I have no idea what it could be with such specific conditions... UPD: it's used to benchmark video player events, so they happens more-less randomly. And for sure it could not be with such precise all the time for some users.